# Pop3 Commands for Tag was read email as Read email

Tags: c#, command, pop3

I use pop 3 command for reading incoming emils from Gmail Account in C#.
and I want to tag as a was read email as a read email after each loop.
Since in each loop all emails get with RETR command.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do this with the POP3 protocol. The POP3 protocol does not allow the client to save any sort of message state.

If you want this functionality, you'll have to use IMAP.